# Invalid access token on accessing unsecured resource oauth2

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented spring-security-oauth2 in application, with lots of efforts. 
And everything is working fine. The resource are being accessed with authorization token only.
But when I try to access unsecure resource , with Authorization Header, it validates access token.

And if the access token is valid then its working right, but if the access token is invalid, it shows me error `Invalid access_token`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring security intercepts every request and check for validity of access_token unless explicitly user specifies to permit the access of URl.
Like if you want not to intercept the url pattern and check the authentication, then code would be like

```
<http ...>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/oauth2/resource/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
```

But if you want to access resources without any security the you can do something like this :

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
```

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

You must be configuring the HTTP pattern in your OAuth configuration file. Check if you configure the URLs with '*'

```
<http pattern="/detail/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <!-- intercept-url pattern -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/detail/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```

For example in above configuration, I have made all the APIs secured which start 'detail'. You may also have unknowingly/unintentionally made an API secured. Make sure you don't!